# Apache2 not generating MIME types for css/js with new install

Tags: apache, apache2, mime-types

I have been struggling with locating the problem with my apache2 install after Lubuntu 21.10 release.  I'm running

Apache 2 Server version: Apache/2.4.48 (Ubuntu)
Server built: 2022-01-05T14:29:15

and PHP 8.0.8

After the OS upgrade, apache2 was surprisingly removed. So I reinstalled it but immediately noticed my localhost testing pages were generating lots of MIME errors and browser issues like for js and css:

> The stylesheet https://localhost/assets/css/main.css?ver=6.1 was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”

I do not get any apache2 errors on startup.

I've tried numerous things:

- TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
- AddType text/css .css

both in top level conf and in the virtualhost specific to this setup.  Does anyone know what I could do to track this problem down or correct it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of attempts to patch the problem. I managed to fully remove and reinstall both php8 and apache2.4, redo all the configurations and SSL and it started working properly again.  The root cause of this issue or how to fix it remains unknown to me, but this did eventually fix the problem.